# How to restrict access to a folder to a specific active directory group in an Asp.Net WebForms application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, active-directory

I have a WebForms application that uses Active Directory for authentication.  The entire company should be able to access the application (and they can), but there are several forms in a "Mgr" folder that should only be accessed by AD group "ta_admins".  I have read several threads on SO, but I can't seem to get anything to work.

I created a Web.config file inside the "Mgr" folder and tried the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
  <configuration>
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow roles = "ta_admins" />
        <deny users = "*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </configuration>
```

I have tried changing "

> Method is only supported if the user name parameter matches the user name in the current Windows Identity.

I am a member of ta_admins.

Here is part of the application's Web.config:

```
<system.web>
  <authorization>
    <deny users="?" />
  </authorization>
  <authentication mode="Windows" />
  <roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider">
    <providers>
      <clear />
      <add name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider" applicationName="/" />
    </providers>
  </roleManager>
  ..............
</system.web>
```

The aspx page has a grid that is populated with the members of a specific AD group.  This works just fine when I'm not attempting to control the user group that can access the "Mgr" folder.  The code behind is below (not sure if it's needed, but just-in-case...):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        dt.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[5]
        {
            new DataColumn("givenName", typeof (string)),
            new DataColumn("sn", typeof (string)),
            new DataColumn("mail", typeof (string)),
            new DataColumn("department", typeof (string)),
            new DataColumn("manager", typeof (string))
        });

        using (var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, null))
        {
            using (var group = (GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, "reps")))
            {
                var users = group.GetMembers(true);
                foreach (UserPrincipal user in users)
                {
                    DirectoryEntry de = user.GetUnderlyingObject() as DirectoryEntry;
                    dt.Rows.Add
                    (
                        Convert.ToString(de.Properties["givenName"].Value),
                        Convert.ToString(de.Properties["sn"].Value),
                        Convert.ToString(de.Properties["mail"].Value),
                        Convert.ToString(de.Properties["department"].Value),
                        Regex.Replace((Convert.ToString(de.Properties["manager"].Value)), @"CN=([^,]*),.*$", "$1")
                    );
                }
                rgAdUsrs.DataSource = dt;
                rgAdUsrs.DataBind();
            }
        }
    }
```

Please let me know if additional information is required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I found and different way to get this done.  I just get a list of all groups the user is in and base form access on that.

```
PrincipalSearchResult<Principal> groups = UserPrincipal.Current.GetGroups();

        IEnumerable<string> groupNames = groups.Select(x => x.SamAccountName);

        if (!groupNames.Contains("ta_admins"))
        {
            Response.Redirect("~/AccessDenied.aspx");
        }
    }
```

Then I disabled directoryBrowse in the web.config of the folder.